# Group by fuzzy condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to group lines in a table by a complicated condition. Let's say I have a table:

```
create table items (
   name text,
   price float
)
```

and it have items like this:

```
foo | 42.0
foo | 42.5
foo | 100
bar | 42
```

first two `foo`'s price different by each other by less than 10% (the condition is something like `a.price / b.price between 0.9 and 1.1`), so they should go to a single group, while other (3rd) `foo` and `bar` should be in separate groups, and expected result should be something like this:

```
item | min_price | max_price | count
foo | 42 | 42.5 | 2
foo | 100 | 100 | 1
bar | 42 | 42 | 1
```

is it possible to do using sql query?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) What if you have rows with 42, 42.5, 43, 43.5, 44, 44.5, 46, 46.5, 47.  The first and last differ by more than 10% but the intermediate values are all within that range.

Comment: 1. I will accept answer for any database, but postgres is preferable. 2. Let's assume that there's no such items, or that they all should fall to a single group

Comment: Can you determine appropriate canonical values for each group, like e.g. "round to nearest multiple of 10"? Or do you need to find the groups dynamically?

Comment: This will not do, because 89 and 90 will go to different groups

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption in your comments, you can look for lags to define where the groups start based on the relative prices.  Then do a cumulative sum of the "group starts" to calculate a grouping id, and aggregate:

```
select item, min(price), max(price), count(*)
from (select i.*,
             count(*) over (filter where prev_price < 0.9 * price) over (partition by item order by price) as grp
      from (select i.*,
                   lag(price) over (partition by item order by price) as prev_price
            from items i
           ) i
     ) i
group by item
order by item, min(price);
```